# Applying stretch value to raster output in ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I've been dabbling in ModelBuilder for a couple of days now on ArcMap 10.8 trying to automate a process for work. We make custom maps for the public and for topographic maps we make a mix of a hillshade and a TIN grid for the background. I managed to build the model and it works great but the output hillshade at the end gets a stretch value of standard deviations, and I want a Min-Max stretch.

Is it possible to specify the stretch value for the hillshade in ModelBuilder?

It is not a big deal to just use Image Analysis and change it with one click, but if I can automate the whole process that would be great.

[image: This is the model i've been working on.]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not to do with your hill shade *dataset* but the raster *layer*. In ArcMap I don't believe the min/max stretch is exposed to any geoprocessing tool, happy to be proven wrong.

In the context of ModelBuilder the way to impose a symbology on your output dataset is to have it prebuilt and saved as a LayerFile (lyr). Then you right click on the output, what you are calling `Makeras_hillSha1` go to properties and set the Layer symbology.

[image: model]

The LayerFile must exist, you can't just set it in modelbuilder and then delete the LayerFile itself, it won't find it and the output defaults to the standard deviation stretch.

Comment: Looks like a solution to me. Thank you!